# The javascript 'self' global variable does not behave as described?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I was looking into a recent issue I had with the 'self' global variable. If I read the mdn description, it states that the self global variable is read-only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self

However, when I try certain experiments, it certainly is not. My issue was that I was working with the webpack dynamic importing. I had set it up in such a way that vendor libraries are being imported dynamically. Now webpack has an entire flow of preparing the promises and executing them, I had the following issue:

So webpack is preparing a 'push' method on the window for the dynamically imported modules to call, as such:

```
i = self.webpackChunkepibase = self.webpackChunkepibase || [];
i.forEach(t.bind(null, 0)),
i.push = t.bind(null, i.push.bind(i))
```

Now, in normal cases, this worked perfect for me. However, on one page, I was getting chunkLoading failed errors. After investigating, I found out that an external script, configured on our page by the customer, was overwriting 'self' with something else completely. Hence, tripping up the next part within the webpack dynamic import flow:

```
(self.webpackChunkepibase = self.webpackChunkepibase || []).push([[303], {
```

Self, was no longer the window object but some random data they pushed in there, and as such, the .push() method was not available.

I have then fixed this by changing my webpack config to use 'window' as the globalObject.

Also, what boggles my mind is, that if you do the following in any random console (or JS file, I would imagine):

```
var self = 'Something'
```

then what you get is:

```
window.self === 'Something' //true
self === 'Something' //true
```

So Question number 1:
Is the MDN information not correct, or is this a bug that has been recently introduced that 'self' is no longer read-only?

Question number 2:
Is the 'var self' modification and its results expected? Is this because self is a 'reserved' keyword or something? I can imagine this can cause quite the confusion?

Question number 3: Is changing the self considered bad practice or not? I guess if it remained in some kind of scope, as I read here and there, it would be okay. However, that is not the case. Modifying self anywhere, seems to be updating it in the global space. As it seems webpack completely disregards any possibility of it being anything else than the Window object, it seems to me 'self' should be left untouched?. I assume there are other libraries that also make this assumption, and playing around with 'self' might cause all kinds of trouble?

Comment: It's read-only (i.e there is no setter) but [replaceable](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#Replaceable) :-/ If only for the reason not to break old scripts that use a global `var self`.

Comment: "*Is changing the self considered bad practice or not?*" - yes, definitely a bad practice.